# created_at is different from DateTime.now

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activerecord, timestamp

Got into a really sticky situation, while saving a model instance I get a value of created_at dated 9 hours ago.

While executing DateTime.now I get exactly the NOW time, as well as when I execute NOW() and current_timestamp on SQL server.

So my question would be:

1. Is it possible to override the default created_at setter method? Or change the timestamp setter? Or how does rails handle setting the create_at method?
2. Is there any config setting settings? Initializers, or anything that might point me to the right direction of setting the created_at method?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Ok, just got by calling `product_review.created_at` #=> Mon, 23 Sep 2013 00:25:31 UTC +00:00

Comment: So that means the time zone is set incorrectly... so may be the question should be how to set the timezone for a Rails engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-c-now

`Time.now` - Returns a Time object initialized to the current system time.

`created_at` - is saved the GMT time, in my case it shows 10.00 for example but my system time is 12.00 as I am 2 hours ahead of GMT.

Set the TimeZone in `environment.rb`:

```
# config/environment.rb
config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
```

Run `rake time:zones:all` to get the actual listing and use the one you need, like `Central Time (US & Canada)`.

Comment: Actually found an answer a minute ago :) thanks, but anyway it is the right answer :)

Comment: http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/1/25/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-easier-timezones